# Как можно через CSS фиксировать соотношении сторон?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

При изменении соотношении сторон фигура сдвигается.
[image: Пример на картинке]

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.element {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 10%;
    top: 20%;
    left: 50%;
}
img.icon {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.backgrounddiv {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="element"><img class="icon" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ninja-things-1/1772/ninja-simple-512.png"></div>
<div class="backgrounddiv">
<img src="https://ak1.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/2090711/thumb/1.jpg">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Так вам фиксировать соотношении сторон надо или фигуру по центру картинки?

Comment: Соотношение сторон, и фигуру, чтобы при изменении соотношений, не съехало, с того места где стоит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Чтобы сделать соотношение сторон 16:9, зададим `background::before`;
- `.element` помещаем внутрь блока с фоном и абсолютно позиционируем по центру.

```css
.background {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    background: url('https://ak1.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/2090711/thumb/1.jpg') no-repeat center;
    z-index: 1;
}

.background::before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 56.25%;
}


.element {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.icon {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
    <div class="element">
        <img class="icon" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ninja-things-1/1772/ninja-simple-512.png">
    </div>
</div>
```